# How much XP/freebie points to pay for True Faith?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

To have True Faith at all, a vampire must buy a 7-point Merit (p. 494 of V20 Corebook). It is also mentioned there that it is possible to lose the rating in True Faith (and, therefore, increase it). 
But how does one do it? Do I pay for it as for Abilities? Or as for... what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

True Faith, as described in the V20 supplement **Hunters Hunted 2**, is a Numina. A dot of True Faith costs 7 freebies at character creation, and you cannot start with more than one, so that's your Merit cost right there. You raise them by spending (Current Level x 7) in XP.

Here’s the rules on how you get permission to raise True Faith, from that supplement:

> True Faith is increased by acts of devotion toward the character’s revered higher power or cause. *Additional points are awarded only at the Storyteller’s discretion, based on appropriate behavior and deeds*. The Storyteller should closely consider the Faithful’s actions during the course of the story and inform the player when he believes that it is appropriate that next level be purchased.

Emphasis added. Now, vampires don’t ordinarily gain access to Numina. And it’s arguable that as a damned creature that drinks blood, you're unlikely to be granted permission. But Storytellers may have more mercy in some games than others, and grace is permitted to even the Kindred. So while my instinct is to say, “You’ll probably never actually get to raise it,” the rules are there to do so.

Comment: There  is precedent though when looking at existing NPCs. Ferrox, a Gargoyle and former Ghoul, for example has a very high true faith rating, 8 or 9 I believe. His backstory paints him as a highly devoted Christian that sets out to rid the world of Satan's spawns. He even shepherds a group of Kinderd to safety as God kills all others during Gehenna. So it can definitely be done, but takes a whole lot of dedication and extensive role playing.

Comment: @Bob Ferox already had a strong faith when he was still alive. As the Embrace wiped his memory out (except the faith), it did suddenly increase drastically. There is a 2 pt. flaw "Amnesia", which is smth like what happened to Ferox, but even if someone tries to build such a character, I would not (obviously) give him True Faith of 8 or 9. There was a Lasombra with True Faith of 4, who has a degree in Theology,  and some other guy, who has the rating of 1. The former is probably a better example of what could be played in a story, especially if the player actually knows a lot aboput religion.

Comment: Before this gets punted off to chat, I'll note this: NPCs, especially canon ones, do not spend XP for their acquisitions. Although some products do make a nod at using the development mechanics to reflect their growth, most do not, and the authors assign points as they will to create the character the story demands.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy I agree. I was merely offering Ferox as an example of a Kindred with a True Faith rating that has grown even after being turned. Any PC with such ambitions will have a very hard time attaining even a basic level and it should be roleplayed thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

DAV20 book has an interesting alternative answer on page 392.

1. You don't pay points to have True Faith at character generation.

   > In game terms, True Faith
   >   does not cost Merit or experience points; it’s a player
   >   choice with Storyteller approval.
2. Neither do you pay to advance in True Faith.

   > Increases in True Faith should come only with Storyteller
   >   approval as a manifestation of the story being told.
   >   There are no systems to abstract what reflects a gain or
   >   loss of this sort of faith.

It might apply stronger to the V20 because Hunters Hunted 2 is a different game, but some Storytellers might prefer the latter to keep all characters on more or less same level of power by forcing them to spend points.

Comment: It also depends on how a Storyteller chooses to run their game. Variances range from strict adherence to costs as prescribed in the book(s) to some story-driven acquisitions without XP cost to games (like one I run) where no XP is ever awarded and all improvements and acquisitions are the result of in-game actions.